# How to slide Detail view with master view

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

I currently have an application which for all intents and purposes may be considered as the basic default master/detail application in xcode. The issue i am facing is that at the moment, when the master view is opened, it simply appears on top of the detail view. like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iCfS.png

i would prefer it if the detail view slid across with the master view so you would see from the edge of the detail view, similar to the facebook app, which i'm sure most are familiar with http://www7.pcmag.com/media/images/320683-facebook-ipad.jpg?thumb=y

If anyone could provide a solution or point me in the direction of one, i would be hugely grateful.

Comment: I don't know you are using a `splitViewController`. But you just have to use `MFSideMenu` for your requirement. you can find it in `github`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of available solutions that you can easily use to achieve the desired effect.

I recently tested ECSlidingViewController and found it to be straight to the point:
https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

If you're interested in doing something fancier, or understanding the mechanics behind such a solution, have a look at Apple's following documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html